# Pandas converting datetime to minutes

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

name = pd.Series(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"])
c1 = pd.Series(["0", "0", "01:56:00", "10:01:00", "120", "2 hours"])
c2 = pd.Series(["00:60:00", "0", "10", "12:00:00", "20 mins", "100"])
df = pd.DataFrame({"name": name, "time1": c1, "time2": c2})
print(df)

  name     time1     time2
0    A         0  00:60:00
1    B         0         0
2    C  01:56:00        10
3    D  10:01:00  12:00:00
4    E       120   20 mins
5    F   2 hours       100
```

In the `time1` and `time2` columns I want to convert the values formatted like a `datetime` (hours:minutes:seconds) into minutes. The desired output is this:

```
  name    time1    time2
0    A        0       60
1    B        0        0
2    C      116       10
3    D      601      720
4    E      120  20 mins
5    F  2 hours      100
```

This is messy because not all values are formatted as a datetime, and some cells contain words (e.g. mins, hours) that I want to leave alone for now

I came up with a method to replace the datetime values by iterating over the rows, checking whether the cell contains `:`, and if so do a simple conversion. However, this method doesn't scale very well. Is there a more natural way to do this in Pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) with [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and where `True` apply output of [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) with output in `ns`, so division is necessary:

```
mask1 = df.time1.str.contains(':')
mask2 = df.time2.str.contains(':')
const = 6 * 10**10 #ns -> min
df.time1 = df.time1.mask(mask1, pd.to_timedelta(df.time1, errors='coerce') / const)
df.time2 = df.time2.mask(mask2, pd.to_timedelta(df.time2, errors='coerce') / const)

print (df)
  name    time1    time2
0    A        0       60
1    B        0        0
2    C      116       10
3    D      601      720
4    E      120  20 mins
5    F  2 hours      100
```

Comment: This appears to work for the example I posted, but for my actual data (which is too large to post here) I get the following error when I try to apply the mask to a column: `bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'`. Where might the error be coming from?

Comment: It seem some NaN in real data, so need parameter `na=False` in `str.contains`.